How do i send data from a fivem FXServer server script to javascript
Client-side
RegisterNetEvent('ch_nui:bob')
AddEventHandler('ch_nui:bob',function (identifier)
    print('1'
)
    CreateThread(function ()
        print('1'
        )
        while true do
            Wait(50)
    
            local playerId = PlayerPedId()
            local playerCoords = GetEntityCoords(playerId)
            local playerHeading = GetEntityHeading(playerId)
    
            SendNUIMessage({
                type = 'position',
                x = playerCoords.x,
                y = playerCoords.y,
                z = playerCoords.z,
                heading = playerHeading,
            })
            SendNUIMessage({
                type='identifierr',
                identifierr = identifier
            })
            
        end
        
    end)
    

end)

TriggerServerEvent('ch_nui:kok')

Server-side
RegisterNetEvent('ch_nui:kok')
AddEventHandler('ch_nui:kok',function ()
    print('2')
    local identifier = GetPlayerIdentifierByType(source,'license')
    TriggerClientEvent('ch_nui:bob',identifier)
end)

For some reason, in any of my code, when i try to trigger a client event from the server it never works, and im just stuck trying to display an value in my sql database for days now,  why is this happening, is there another easier way to transfer data from server to javascript.
My js file is this
if(data.type === 'identifier'){
        const identifier = data.identifierr
    }
    const money = MySQL.scalar('SELECT `money` FROM `money` WHERE `identifier` = ? LIMIT 1', [
        identifier
      ])

      console.log(money)

Although it doesnt matter because the problem is that the client event doesnt get triggered
I tried the code, played around with events stuff and nothing worked ever, im just really stuck rn i've hit a brick wall and i dont understand
